# PYTHONPATH overwritten when running under supervisord

Tags: python, supervisord, pythonpath

I have the following supervisor program config:

```
[program:showvars]
environment=TESTVAR=hi,PYTHONPATH=/home/eric/python/tools/
command=python /home/eric/showvars.py
```

where showvars.py simply loops through the environment variables and prints their values:

```
import os
for param in os.environ.keys():
    print "%20s %s" % (param,os.environ[param])
```

I get the following (abridged) output:

```
         TESTVAR hi
      PYTHONPATH /
```

What could be resetting my PYTHONPATH?

Answer (score 2):

Surrounding the path with quotes fixes this:

```
[program:showvars]
environment=TESTVAR=hi,PYTHONPATH='/home/eric/python/tools/'
command=python /home/eric/showvars.py
```